# Unable to use the inbuilt _registerListenersForTrackedConditions() method for tracked conditions and related HTML listeners

Tags: tracker, apache-unomi

I have to track form event using unomi, so I found that while using startTracker() method to start the web tracker, it's also calling  _registerListenersForTrackedConditions() method provided in script ( /tracker/unomi-web-tracker.js) by unomi.

`if (!wem.disableTrackedConditionsListeners) { wem._registerListenersForTrackedConditions(); }`

issue :-

Not able to execute line no. 2 -  **wem._registerListenersForTrackedConditions();** .and if condition is satisfying (**!wem.disableTrackedConditionsListeners** = true )

is there any other way to use this _registerListenersForTrackedConditions() or anything I am missing ? please let me know.